# continue function is shutting down my PHP forloop

Tags: php, for-loop, shopify, break, continue

So im building a CSV uploader for my customers to upload orders to my website on Shopify with PHP.
If you look through my code, you'll see 2 instances where I set `$errors` to be `TRUE`. Then, after all the error possibilities, I check if `$errors` is true and if yes, `continue` the loop so that the order is not processed. For some reason, it is stopping the entire forloop like a `break` would do. Any help with this from the community? Here's my code:

```
$url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json';
  $rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['CSV']);
  $customer = $_POST['customer'];
  $thisID = explode(',', $_POST['IDs']);
  $lines = count($rows);
  $IDs = count($thisID);
  for ($x = 0; $x < $lines; $x++) {
    $ordtot = 0;
    $cells = str_getcsv($rows[$x]);
    $line_items = array();
    $POs = array();
if ($x > 0){
    $csmpo = $cells[0];
    $orddte = $cells[1];
    $shipvia = $cells[2];
    $shipdte = $cells[3];
    $cncldte = $cells[4];
    $ohsname = $cells[5];
    $ohsaddr1 = $cells[6];
    $ohsaddr2 = $cells[7];
    $ohscity = $cells[8];
    $ohsstate = $cells[9];
    $ohszip = $cells[10];
    $ohsphone = $cells[11];
    $oddpart = $cells[12];
    $oddupc = $cells[13];
    $oddprice = $cells[14];
    $oddordqty = $cells[15];
    $ohdnote = $cells[16];
    if ($ohsphone == ""){
        $ohsphone = "1111111111";
    }
    for($a = 0; $a <= $IDs; $a++){
        if ($a == $IDs){
            $result .= "Order " . $csmpo . " NOT processed, item " . $oddpart . " not found. Please contact the webmaster.<br>";
            $error = true;
            break 1;
        }
        $myID = explode('/', $thisID[$a]);
        $mySKU = explode('_', $thisID[$a]);
        if ($mySKU[0] == $oddpart){
            $line_items[] = array('variant_id' => $myID[1], 'quantity' => $oddordqty);
            $ordtot = $ordtot + $oddordqty;
            break 1;
        }
    }
    $lines2 = $lines - $x;
    $w = $x + 1;
    for ($y = $w; $y < $lines2; $y++){
        $cells2 = str_getcsv($rows[$y]);
        if ($cells2[0] == $csmpo){
            for($b = 0; $b <= $IDs; $b++){
                if ($b == $IDs){
                    $result .= "Order " . $csmpo . " NOT processed, item " . $oddpart . " not found. Please contact the webmaster.<br>";
                    $error = true;
                    break 1;
                }
                $myID = explode('/', $thisID);
                $mySKU = explode('_', $thisID);
                if ($mySKU[0] == $cells2[12]){
                    $line_items[] = array('variant_id' => $myID[1], 'quantity' => $cells2[15]);
                    $ordtot = $ordtot + $cells2[15];
                    break 1;
                }
            }
            $x = $x + 1;
        } else {
            break 1;
        }
    }
    if ($error){continue;}
$order = array(
  "order" => array(
    "customer" => array(
      "id" => $customer
    ),
    "financial_status" => "pending",
    "shipping_address" => array(
                        "first_name" => '',
                        "address1" => $ohsaddr1,
                        "addres2" => $ohsaddr2,
                        "phone" => $ohsphone,
                        "city" => $ohscity,
                        "zip" => $ohszip,
                        "province" => $ohsstate,
                        "country" => "United States",
                        "last_name" => $ohsname,
                        "name" => $ohsname,
                        "country_code" => "US",
                        "province_code" => $ohsstate
    ),
    /*"billing_address" => array(
                        "first_name" => '',
                        "address1" => $_POST["bill_address1"],
                        "phone" => $_POST["bill_phone"],
                        "city" => $_POST["bill_city"],
                        "zip" => $_POST["bill_zip"],
                        "province" => $_POST["bill_state"],
                        "country" => "United States",
                        "last_name" => $_POST["bill_name"],
                        "name" => $_POST["bill_name"],
                        "country_code" => "US",
                        "province_code" => $_POST["bill_state"]
    ),*/
    "line_items" => $line_items,
    "note_attributes" => array(
                    array("name" => "POnumber",
                          "value" => $csmpo),
                    array("name" => "shipdate", 
                          "value" => $shipdte),
                    array("name" => "canceldate", 
                          "value" => $cncldte)
    ),
    "gateway" => "Achim Credit Terms"
)); 
$session = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($order)); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$APIresult = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
usleep(500000);
$result .= "Processed Order " . $csmpo . " for a total of " . $ordtot . " items, shipping to " . $ohdcity . ", " . $ohdstate . "<br>";
}
  }
  print_r($result);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Consider refactor, your code is not readable. Do you have to use curl in for loop?

Comment: You can do the same thing as with `break` https://secure.php.net/continue

Comment: @PatNowak Yes, it has to create a new order for each line (or two, if there are more than one SKU ordered) in the CSV sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you never reset `$error` to false, so once $error becomes true it stays true for all further iterations.

Reset $error in the first line of your loop:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $lines; $x++) {
    $error = false;
    ....
```

Comment: I can't believe after 5 years of programming, I left this out. Thanks Simon. Works now. BTW, if anybody has comments on the code (took me a while to build, and its my first PHP program), I would appreciate it.